# "The specified solution configuration "Debug|AnyCPU" is not valid" error when building solution via Microsoft.Build

Tags: c#, msbuild

I need to compile an old WPF project written in VB via code. For this I'm writing a class library in C# that loads the solution and invokes a build process.

Code as follows:

```
// solution_file is a FileInfo object that points to the .sln file
// logger is a class that implements ILogger
var solution = new ProjectCollection();
var solution_properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
solution_properties.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
solution_properties.Add("Platform", "AnyCPU");
var build_parameters = new BuildParameters(solution);
var logger = new SimpleLogger();
build_parameters.Loggers = new List<ILogger>() { logger };
var build_request = new BuildRequestData(
    solution_file.FullName,
    solution_properties,
    "14.0",
    new string[] { "Build" },
    null);
var build_result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(build_parameters, build_request);
if (build_result.OverallResult != BuildResultCode.Success)
    throw new Exception();
```

Problem is, in every case the build falis with the following error:

`The specified solution configuration "Debug|AnyCPU" is not valid. Specify a valid solution configuration with the properties Configuration and Platform (eg. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug  /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave these properties empty to use the default solution configuration.`

(Message might not be an exact translation, I'm translating from Spanish.)

Any combination of Configuration (Debug or Release) and Platform (x86, x64 or AnyCPU) fails with the same error (the only thing that changes is the `The specified solution configuration Debug|AnyCPU is not valid` part. If I leave these properties empty, the error message is the same with `Debug|MCD` instead of `Debug|AnyCPU`.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the error message it's very clear, you used "AnyCPU" when it must be "Any CPU"

Comment: What happens when you call `MSBuild.exe Solution.sln` from the command line?

Comment: Turns out I can't read a proper error message. Gusman, please post this as an answer so I can mark/upvote it. Thanks to everyone who took time to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROTIP: Next time, kids, read the error messages properly. I was passing as platform "Any CPU" instead of "AnyCPU" (note the non-existant space in the correct term).